# EventLoopScheduler seems to stop executing the scheduled events

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I have created an `EventLoopScheduler` like so:

```
eventLoopScheduler = new EventLoopScheduler(ts =>
    new Thread(ts)
    {
        Name = "UpdatesEventLoop",
        IsBackground = true
    });
```

And on top of that I created a scheduler:

```
updatesScheduler = eventLoopScheduler.Catch<Exception>(e =>
{
    Log.Error("Error on updates thread", e);
    return false;
});
```

Now, I have an external data source which publishes updates pretty often. I listen for these updates and pass them on, eventually updating the UI. It looks something like this:

```
updatesObservable.Subscribe(x =>
{
    //Do some data checking then pass it along
    updatesScheduler.Schedule(() =>
    {
        //subject exists and is just a Subject of type "Update"
        subject.OnNext(theUpdate); 
    });
});
```

Everything works fine when I start my app. Updates flow in and the `updatesObservable` gets them, passes them along and the scheduler performs the action right away.

However, something goes wrong sometimes. The source of the updates bounces overnight so there is an interruption in the data (I am not sure this is the cause of my problem though as the app reconnects to the source once it is up again). When I get back to the office in the morning and look at the app, the GUI is showing stale data, and no new updates are happening.

I attached the debugger and I could see that `updatesObservable` was getting updates from the source normally and passing them on to the scheduler, however, the scheduler never actually executes the `Action` (in this case `subject.OnNext(theUpdate)` is never called).

I am having trouble trying to figure out what might have caused the `EventLoopScheduler` to just stop executing the scheduled `Actions` as I do not know much of it's inner workings.

As I was trying to figure it out I had a look inside of `eventLoopScheduler`.  I noticed that the `_evt` field (the `SemaphoreSlim`) had a very high `CurrentCount` and it was constantly increasing.  I compared this `CurrentCount` value to what I see when the app is running as expected and when everything is working ok `CurrentCount` hovers around 0-20, sometimes reaching the low 100s but quickly going back down to zero. In the broken state, `CurrentCount` goes to 100,000s and never decreases.

Any suggestions as to what might be happening here? Does the `CurrentCount` tell me anything (not sure exactly what it represents)?  Is that confirmation that something is not working right?

Thanks. Please let me know if anything is unclear.

Comment: What you really need to do is provide a [mcve] for us to work with. Right now this would just be guess work and that doesn't make for a good question on SO.

Comment: @Enigmativity  Yeah.  Unfortunately this is part of a large project and I was not able to isolate and reproduce it.  I posted the question with the hope that there was someone more familiar with how the EventLoopScheduler works and maybe there were some common causes or things to check in cases where it stops running scheduled tasks.

Comment: Are you seeing the error logged from the catch scheduler? Quick look at the CatchScheduler class suggests that returning false from the exception handler will rethrow the exception which - given this error isn't perpetuated to the subscriber - could cause issues.

Comment: @Flack - I think you need to persevere in creating a [mcve]. Doing so will either isolate the problem or help you find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on my comment above, it seems to me - and I'm afraid I haven't had an opportunity to confirm this yet - that allowing the CatchScheduler to throw the exception causes the worker thread in the EventLoopScheduler to abort. As the exception isn't perpetuated to the subscriber, the subscription stays alive but and the EventLoopScheduler keeps enqueing work - hence the increasing CurrentCount - but no thread exists to process the enqued items.

You should be able to prove this my:
a) returning true in the exception handler and seeing if the problem is resolved (although your subscription will likely be torn down when the exception occurs),
b) making the EventLoopScheduler's worker thread foreground (IsBackground = false) and seeing if you app crashes or,
c) removing the Catch on the dispatcher and using Observable.Catch instead.

I assume the author of the Catch extension method for the dispatcher intended for the Catch clauses to be nested so that the exception flowed in the same manner as the C# Catch block until at least on block handles the exception but I feel this behaviour is dangerous for exactly the reason you're encountering.

Do let me know if this helps as I am intrigued by the CatchScheduler and it's implementation.